# HEAD XMLHttpRequest on Chromium

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get the HEAD response with an XMLHttpRequest in Chromium to retrive the location URL of a compressed url, but it fails:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() { if (ajax.readyState == 4) alert(ajax.getResponseHeader("Location")) };
ajax.open('HEAD', "http://bit.ly/4Agih5", false);
ajax.send();

// Refused to get unsafe header "Location"
// Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

Comment: this only fails on Chrome? I'm not so sure you can do what you are trying cross-domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mohamed indicated, you will have to create a proxy service on the same site that you are hosting your page on as this is a cross domain request.

This should be failing in all browsers, unless you have explicitly allowed cross domain requests in your Browser.  If bit.ly supported cross domain requests via the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea) for Access-Control-Allow-Origin then your code would work.

Comment: Your language is a bit weird when talking about the W3C Access Control specification. You're also referring to a non existing header (`Access-Control-Allow-Max-Age`) while you actually meant to talk about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: Fixed it for you (and people coming after)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do cross-domain XHRs. Use a web programming language like JSP/Python/PHP/Ruby/etc..