# JavaScript ping a URL and get the redirected URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

In our AngularJS app I have an image URL like:

```
http://example.com/images/get/785746378
```

The issue is this redirects me to another URL which blocked:

```
http://another-example.com/images/f/gs/s/your-image.jpg
```

So the image is not working, but if I replace the domain so it's:

```
http://example.com/images/f/gs/s/your-image.jpg
```

It works fine.

So I want to be able to ping the URL in JavaScript and find out what the redirected URL is and change the domain so it works before adding it to my `img src`

Comment: Have you tried anything? Maybe making an ajax request to the URL?

Comment: What HEADERS it returns? Try it detecting through XHR HEAD

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698178/how-can-i-get-the-redirect-url-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
  var xhr = response.target;
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 302) {
    var redirectURL = xhr.location;
    var imageURL = redirectURL.replace('http://another-example','http://example');
    // change your image src here by imageURL
  }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/images/get/785746378', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your post how you are requesting the image. Assuming that you are requesting it using AJAX / $HTTP:

You can send `HEAD` request for original URL. If HTTP `HEAD` requests are allowed on the server, you will get the HTTP 302 response with new `location` in the response header. You can do the required manipulation on this `location` and send `GET` request for the new URL of the image.